# Sources and Tuts for Facebook FBML?

Tags: facebook, fbml

How to start building pages with Facebook **FBML**.
There is a good sources and tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **DON'T**!
Why would you bother learning an *old* technology?! Facebook is in [the process of deprecating it](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/):

> **We are in the process of deprecating**
>    **FBML**. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please
>   implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our
>   JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to
>   embedded many of the same social
>   features available in FBML. While
>   there is still functionality that we
>   have not ported over yet, we are no
>   longer adding new features to FBML.

Comment: If you want to learn creating am iframe App instead you may find this guide helpfull: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

Comment: Thank you so much. Whats the current option? If I need to crates Facebook pages.

Comment: It's already stated in the answer, html, JS and CSS! for facebook interaction, the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)